# Bluez-5.36 StartDiscovery() method

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I have searched for the method `StartDiscovery()` in **bluez-5.36 libraries** and I could not find.

Can some one please tell where this method is implemented?

Its mentioned in `"adapter-api.txt`" of "`bluez-5.36/doc`/" directory.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer by @jorgemartinez, `StartDiscovery` (and all the other official bluez APIs) are DBUS APIs. Your application will call this via a DBUS invocation. It will be serviced by the `bluetoothd` daemon which does the real work. The implementation on the `bluetoothd` side for that API is the `start_discovery` function in [adapter.c](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/blob/master/src/adapter.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install `BlueZ` with the experimental flag enabled. BlueZ is moving towards user space development by using the DBus to expose bluetooth 'objects' and associated methods and properties.

If you install `d-feet`you can actually check out the methods and types of objects described in the API documentation:

`sudo apt-get install d-feet`

However, for GATT-related functionality, the experimental flag has to be enabled.
If you're not sure how to enable the experimental flag, you can just run `sudo bluetoothd -E` to enable the Bluetooth Daemon with the experimental flag. The corresponding `GattManager1` interfaces and such will be published in the DBus interface, which again, I strongly recommend using `d-feet` to get an idea of how it all works.

If you're looking for some source code and documentation/help regarding the use of and programming with the DBus API, you might want to check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767053/bluez-programming/32958792#32958792).

Answer (score 1):

That is to use bluez through D-Bus API and GATT. In order to access to this feature you need to compile bluez with some experimental features (GATT/D-Bus API is still experimental). Then you can use D-Bus API to access to Adapter and execute the methods on it (Start/StopDiscovery)

Please have a look at this project: https://github.com/jomarmar/bluez-experimental . It is just a fork of bluez, with some changes in order to activate the GATT API experimental feature.