# bluez: connection error with 5

Tags: bluez, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
hci_le_create_conn(device,htobs(0x0010),htobs(0x0010),0,0,
                     peeraddr,0,15,15,0,3200,1,1,0,1000);
```

I get `errno  =  5` form above, and it means that the command has not been received and is not being processed in the host controller.

Could someone tell me where is wrong?

I want to connect my bluetooth smart device with my linux computer, but it not works.
Here is the fucntion  `hci_le_create_conn`'s params below.

```
int hci_le_create_conn(int dd, uint16_t interval, uint16_t window,
        uint8_t initiator_filter, uint8_t peer_bdaddr_type,
        bdaddr_t peer_bdaddr, uint8_t own_bdaddr_type,
        uint16_t min_interval, uint16_t max_interval,
        uint16_t latency, uint16_t supervision_timeout,
        uint16_t min_ce_length, uint16_t max_ce_length,
        uint16_t *handle, int to)
```

Comment: Do you really have to use hci_lib rather than the DBUS interface? hci_lib is not officially supported and going down that route is just a pathway to pain IMHO (I've previously evaluated it).

Comment: @kaylum - does the DBUS interface allow accessing GATT attributes that are non-standard and/or not part of a profile?  When I started with Bluez I was told I couldn't do that with DBUS so I ended up using kernel calls (which is what the shared library ultimately does).

Comment: @TimTisdall Yes it does. As of two or three months ago. The new [gatt API](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt) is now available. But it is still technically experimental and is made available by passing -E to bluetoothd. I've used it and it works well.

Comment: Check out my included answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767053/bluez-programming/32958792#32958792) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281145/bluez-5-36-startdiscovery-method/34330349#34330349) for more information on the DBus interface!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bluetooth daemon to reset your hardware:

`sudo bluetoothctl`

`power off`

`power on`

I believe BlueZ is in the process of phasing out tools like `hciconfig` and `hcitool`. More information can be found [here](http://www.bluez.org/the-management-interface/).

Answer (score -1):

I should run `sudo hciconfig hci0 down` and `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` before run the function.

Anyway, I successfully connected to my BLE device!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what `hciconfig hci0 reset` does.

Comment: go through source code of hciconfig hci0 reset and implement similar feature in your program ,so every time you dont need to issue it from command line

Comment: `hciconfig` is being phased out of BlueZ, just as `hcitool` and the like is. It makes use of raw socket calls. Please do not recommend these as an answer.