# Is gdbus part of Bluez, glib, or neither?

Tags: bluetooth, glib, dbus, bluez

I'm following the [advice of Zimano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767053/bluez-programming?lq=1#) on using the Bluez client as an example to implement Bluetooth in my Linux application.

I have installed:

```
libbluetooth-dev
libglib2.0-dev
libdbus-1-dev
```

The Bluez client example uses a D-Bus helper library that is included as part of Bluez in a gdbus folder when the [soure code](http://www.bluez.org/) is downloaded.

I have looked at it for a few hours and I think if I want to follow the Bluez client example, I need to add and compile the gdbus source from the Bluez source with my program. My question is, do I have that wrong? Is that gdbus included elsewhere? The naming is so close to files in glib-2.0/gio  that I am concerned that I am missing something.

Comment: Looking at it a little more, I believe I need to build bluez from the source to get access to everything needed to implement something similar to the example. Will try that...

Answer (score 3):

[GDBus is part of GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html), which is distributed with GLib.

Based on the package names you've provided I'm guessing you are using a Debian-derived distribution, [so `libglib2.0-dev` is the package you need](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gio-2.0.pc&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any).

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed quite a mess for naming. It appears to be that:

1. Official Glib Dbus library is named "GDBus", BUT it is part of "GIO" => thus you would (*) need (<glib.h> and) <gio/gio.h> , not <gdbus.h>
2. Bluez "gdbus.h" is their completely own local support library not found anywhere in binary form as such, also their license is restrictive for free inclusion.

(*) But of course the Bluez client still remains dependent on their own "gdbus.h" support library.