# Using bluetooth with python and dbus

Tags: python, bluetooth, dbus

As the title suggests.

I am having hard time in finding a decent python dbus module for this one.  There was a lot of smoke, mirrors & traps on the way.

First, let' see what I did.

The first booby-trap was [dbus-python](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/tutorial.html#connecting-to-the-bus).  Couldn't make it to work at all.  Even the examples are broken.

It seems to be outdated, and replaced by [pydbus](https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus/blob/master/doc/tutorial.rst#connecting-to-the-bus)

(The copyright owners / authors for both of them seem to be the same)

Let's see pydbus then.  Also there, the examples don't work that great:

```
from pydbus import SystemBus
bus = SystemBus()
dev = bus.get('.NetworkManager', 'Devices/0')
```

gives

```
KeyError: 'object does not export any interfaces; you might need to pass object path as the 2nd argument for get()'
```

However, if we try something completely contrary to that error message..

```
dev = bus.get('.NetworkManager')
```

we get a nice object with lots of methods:

```
dir(dev)
['ActivateConnection',
 'ActivatingConnection',
 'ActiveConnections',
 'AddAndActivateConnection',
 'AllDevices',
 'Capabilities',
 'CheckConnectivity',
 'CheckPermissions',
 'CheckpointCreate',
 'CheckpointDestroy',
 'CheckpointRollback',
 'Connectivity',
 ....
 ]
```

So far so good.  Let's see if we can get our hands on bluetooth with that one:

```
dev = bus.get('org.bluez')
dir(dev)
['Introspect',
 'RegisterAgent',
 'RegisterProfile',
 'RequestDefaultAgent',
 'UnregisterAgent',
 'UnregisterProfile'
 ]
```

So, again a nice object with some methods.  However most of the things are missing.  Let's take a look for example at this:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt

Can't get that mentioned "Connect" method with pydbus..?

Please don't suggest me to use subprocess.Popen with bluetoothctl - how lame is that. Besides, I want to learn dbus.

**Questions:**

- How to get access to all bluetooth methods?
- What would be the correct dbus python binding to use (that actually works)?
- Any working example would be highly appreciated.
- **I want to achieve bt pairing using python**

Some references:

- Another SO question: [Bluez Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767053/bluez-programming)
- Dbus specs: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc
- Source code for the celebrated `bluetoothctl` program that comes with modern debian linux distros: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/client/main.c
- Nice dbus article: https://medium.com/cesar-update/exposing-a-d-bus-interface-in-linux-part-2-90374a9e381b

**EDIT:**

There is, of course, the python [bluez](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez) library.  But that's GPL licensed.  And there is no way to pair devices with bluez, right?

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:** I created a demo for all of this (python + dbus + bluetooth) here: https://github.com/elsampsa/btdemo

Have fun.

*no need to go further from here - just use that repo*

Some more libraries & tutorials I found on the way:

An article at Medium: https://medium.com/@trstringer/talking-to-systemd-through-dbus-with-python-53b903ee88b1

Bluetool library: https://github.com/emlid/bluetool

dbus specs: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces

My comments about dbus-python were premature.  Bluetool uses it, and by following bluetool's code I was able to go forward a bit:

```
import dbus

def my_pprint(obj, intend = 0):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            print(intend*" "+str(key)+" : ")
            my_pprint(value, intend = intend + 4)
        print()
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for value in obj:
            my_pprint(value, intend = intend + 4)
        print()
    elif isinstance(obj, dbus.Byte ):
         print(intend*" "+ hex(obj) )
    else:
        print(intend*" "+str(obj))
    

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
proxy_object = bus.get_object("org.bluez","/")
manager = dbus.Interface(proxy_object, "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager")
objects = manager.GetManagedObjects()
my_pprint(objects) # see DUMP 1 in the end of this answer
```

i.e., the bluez dbus interface implements an [object manager](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces), giving a nice nested structure of objects (see the dump below)

What is (not) implemented at the bluez dbus interface, can be confirmed with this:

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest [Service] --object-path [Object path]
```

where Server & Object path come from the API docs [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt)

For example:

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest org.bluez --object-path /org/bluez
gdbus introspect --system --dest org.bluez --object-path /
gdbus introspect --system --dest org.bluez --object-path /org/bluez/hci0
```

I'll update this answer once I achieve pairing..

*DUMP1 from the code snippet*

```
/org/bluez : 
    org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable : 

    org.bluez.AgentManager1 : 

    org.bluez.ProfileManager1 : 

/org/bluez/hci0 : 
    org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable : 

    org.bluez.Adapter1 : 
        Address : 
            9C:B6:D0:8C:5D:D6
        AddressType : 
            public
        Name : 
            sampsa-xps13
        ...
        ...
        
    org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties : 

    org.bluez.GattManager1 : 

    org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1 : 
        ActiveInstances : 
            
        SupportedInstances : 
            
        SupportedIncludes : 
                tx-power
                appearance
                local-name


    org.bluez.Media1 : 

    org.bluez.NetworkServer1 : 
    
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_58_C9_35_2F_A1_EF : 
    org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable : 

    org.bluez.Device1 : 
        Address : 
            58:C9:35:2F:A1:EF
        AddressType : 
            public
        Name : 
            Nokia 5
        Alias : 
            Nokia 5
        Class : 
            5898764
        Icon : 
            phone
        Paired : 
            1
        Trusted : 
            0
        Blocked : 
            0
        ...
        ...

    org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties : 

    org.bluez.Network1 : 
        Connected : 
            0

    org.bluez.MediaControl1 : 
        Connected : 
            0

[any other devices follow]
```

Comment: Hi Sampsa. Did you get any further with pairing?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with `bluetool` (on a Raspberry Pi zero w 2), since I needed only functions to scan, pair, connect, disconnect, trust bluetooth devices I just copied `bluetool.py` and `bluezutils.py` to my project. This way I did not need to add the `tcpbridge` dependency and the code is working fine with Python 3. Note that there might be other quirks with Python 3, check this thread: https://github.com/emlid/bluetool/issues/4

Then this is how I use it:

```py
from bluetool import Bluetooth

b = Bluetooth()
print("starting scan")
b.scan(timeout = 10)
print("PAIR")
print(str(b.get_devices_to_pair()))# not paired devices
# print(str(b.get_available_devices()))
s1 = b.pair("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX")# your BT device's MAC
ss = b.trust("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX")# prevents yes/no prompt
s2 = b.connect("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX")
print(str(s1) + " :::::::: " + str(s2))
print("connected:" + str(b.get_connected_devices()))
```

#### Debugging

First try to connect with `bluetoothctl`. If it fails then this script wont work either.

If it does not work it can be because of multiple causes, most common ones are `pulseaudio` not running, not able to connect with `a2dp profile` (if this is the case it will connect and immediately disconnect) and permissions (try running as sudo)